# Need to understand why expressjs is redirecting to index.html

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following server file, using express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var port    =   process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);

// get an instance of router
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

// route middle-ware that will happen on every request
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // log each request to the console
    console.log(req.method, req.url + " logging all requests");
    // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
    next(); 
});

// home page route for port 8080, gets executed when entering localhost:8080
// and redirects to index.html (correctly and as expected)
router.get('/', function(req, res) { 
  console.log("routing from route")
  res.redirect('index.html');
});

 // This gets executed when my url is: http://localhost:8080/test
 // and redirects to index.html (the questions is why!? I thought
 // all the requests to root route would be caught by the router instance

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  console.log('redirecting to index.html'); 
  res.redirect('/index.html');          
 });
```

Looking at the code above and my comments, I cannot understand why

```
app.get('*', function(){...})
```

does not get executed when URL is 
`localhost:8080/index.html` but gets executed when URL is `localhost:8080/test`

Even though, this is the behavior that I was hoping for, I'm not sure why this works?

I don't have a "test.html" page in the root.
One other thing, the index.html does load other scripts, so I expected

```
app.get('*', function(){...})
```

to get executed for such get requests too, as it is supposed to be the catch all, but it does not.

Does `app.use('/', router)` mean that any route that has single character "/" should be handled by Router instance (as long as not a static file)? so "http:localhost:8080" gets interpreted as "http://localhost:8080/"?

I would appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This line-

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));`

will run first. It will see that `index.html` exists and serve that file statically.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is my assumption regarding the second question correct: "Does app.use('/', router) mean that any route that has single character "/" should be handled by Router instance (as long as not a static file)? so "http:localhost:8080" gets interpreted as "http://localhost:8080/"?"